# installing ubuntu without partition

Tags: mint

I am currently using mint.How can I replace it with ubuntu without any data,files loosing?
Can anyone tell me how to boot only ubuntu without  any personal data loss?
Thanks!

Comment: Always, always, always plan for data loss. You should be backing up your user data regularly, and you really need to back it up before you upgrade, reinstall, or install a new operating system. Installing Ubuntu from a live USB should give you the option to replace Mint with Ubuntu without overwriting your data. I've found it to be generally reliable, but I always backup my data first.

Comment: if your home and root are two different partitions, then simply choose to replace mint when installing Ubuntu. your home partition will be safe.

Comment: As far as I know this is only possible **If you have `/home` and `/` on two different partitions.**

Answer (score 0):

create partitions and install Ubuntu along with mint OS after that move all your personal data from mint to Ubuntu folder once you with that you can uninstall  mint.